# bash array with new line as IFS

Tags: arrays, bash

why is this not producing the expected array of results

```
IFS=$'\n'; read -a list <<< `lsblk` ; echo ${list[*]};
```

Because I need to add to this question I have to say that I am a bit confused as to why

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
IFS=$'\n'; readarray list < <(lsblk)
```

And maybe it's better to check the result this way:

```
for i in ${list[@]}; do echo $i; done
```

The `<(lsblk)` there is called process substitution, you can read about it in the **Process Substitution** section of `man bash`.

On systems without `readarray`, you could do like this instead:

```
IFS=$'\n'; while read line; do list+=($line); done < <(lsblk)
```

Comment: readarray though works is not on the bsd machines i need it to be on = /

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to use **-l** flag to get a list of devices, because by default **lsblk** output is in some tree view. (I don't have lsblk, but with lsusb I have expected result):

```
IFS=$'\n'; read -a list <<< `lsblk -l` ; echo ${list[*]};
```

You can also try the more native way of array creation below:

```
list=( $(lsblk -l) ); echo ${list[*]}
```

Comment: @JamesAndino  Then, what means "not producing" ?

Comment: an array of all block devices recognized by the system

Comment: No the output of that echo with no quotes though looses information would still produce an output I can tell its working from as opposed to the out put of my command thats wronger then the just wrong input of my poor echo

Comment: @JamesAndino Isn't it that lsblk produces by default output in some tree format, maybe you wanted list?