# Converting lines of text to an array

Tags: bash

In my bash script I have a variable, `myvar` which when echo'd prints multiple lines.

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
...
```

I want to convert the lines into an array and be able to iterate over it.

```
for i in "${myvar[@]}"
do
    echo "Line is: $i"
done
```

But this just gives:

```
Line is line1
line2
line3
line4
...
```

any tips?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447744/bash-array-with-new-line-as-ifs/20447815#20447815

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `myvar` just has one string, to make `myvar` having array each of lines.

```
#!/bin/bash

let -a myvar;

for line in `cat test.txt`
do
    myvar+=($line)
done

for i in "${myvar[@]}"
do
    echo "Line is: $i"
done
```

**output**

```
Line is: line1
Line is: line2
Line is: line3
Line is: line4
```

### UPDATED - performance test

- CentOS : 6.4 (runs on VirtualBox)
- bash : 4.2.5
- $filename is 40MB, contains 120k lines and  each of line approximately 300 bytes long.
- Q1

  ```
  for line in `cat $filename`
  do
      myvar+=($line)
  done
  ```
- Q2

  ```
  myvar=(`cat $filename`)
  ```
- Q3

  ```
  mapfile -t myvar < "$filename"
  ```

**Results**

- Q1 : 28 sec.
- Q2 : 11 sec.
- Q3 : < 1 sec. (Wow~!)

Comment: Please, stop showing bad practices: you're using a subshell with outdated backticks, forking on a `cat`, and all this to show broken code! `-1` well-deserved.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thank you for advising me. OP, feel free to accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have a variable with newlines; maybe you should review your design!

Anyways, in bash 4, the cleanest and most efficient way is to use `mapfile`:

```
myvar=$'line1\nline2\nline3\nline 4 with spaces in it\nline 5 with no trailing newline'

mapfile -t myarray <<< "$myvar"

for i in "${myarray[@]}"; do
    echo "Line is: $i"
done
```

There's another possibility, fiddling with `IFS`, but that's too ugly for this purpose.

Notice that, unlike the accepted answer (which shows terrible bash practices — you guys should definitely stop supporting bad practices and broken codes), this works fine with spaces.

Now, if your variable `myvar` is in fact obtained from a file (since you accepted the answer that shows this, it might be your case), to directly obtain the content of the file `file.txt` in an array, the fields of which being the lines of the file, use:

```
mapfile -t myarray < "file.txt"

for i in "${myarray[@]}"; do
    echo "Line is: $i"
done
```

And it will be more efficient too.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable contains new lines as escaped character `\n`, then you need to `echo -e` to make it an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myvar="Line1\nLine2\nLine3";
arr=$(echo -e $myvar)

for i in $arr
do
    echo $i
done
```